# Application Insights - Querying Collections

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm using Serilog to trace data to Application Insights.

In the custom properties, serilog logs a collection of faults as custom data like this...

```
faults.Count 2
faults.0 "SomeFault" 
faults.1 "AnotherFault"
```

How can I query these properties using Application Insights Analytics query language?

I want to report on any responses which contain `"AnotherFault"` without knowing the index.

Comment: Can you post an example of the whole content of the customdimensions property ?

Comment: A screenshot of the custom dimension is better:)

Comment: This is exactly how the data is presented under Custom Data. 

A screenshot wouldn't show anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be something as simple as:

```
search in (CustomEvents) "AnotherFault"
```

Alternatively, you can limit search to only custom dimensions:

```
CustomEvents
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| where tostring(customDimensions) contains "AnotherFault"
```

Both will have its performance implications on large data sets due to string containment comparisons, so knowing either index or name or the property will definitely help here.

Another way is to perform `| mvexpand` and unfold each of the custom dimensions into its own row:

```
CustomEvents
| where timstamp > ago(24h)
| project customDimensions, usefulField1, usefulField2,....
| mvexpand bagexpansion=array customDimensions
| where customDimensions[1] == "AnotherFault"
```

By converting it to array, you can access the value of the custom dimension by generic [1] rather than by knowing its name, so you can do a full comparison to "AnotherFault" without using "faults.#" syntax. The trick is to reduce the amount of the fields you'd like to see before you do `mvexpand` to reduce memory multiplication.